# How can I integrate the Visual Studio Code (VSCode) Java Language Server into my project for the purpose of constructing a call graph

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol, call-graph

I know that the VS Code Java extension has a standalone Java Language Server. Now, I want to build a call graph for Java projects. Note that some projects may not be compilable. So traditional tools like Soot and WALA won't work. Can someone guide me on starting the Java Language Server alone and writing a new client independant of VS Code editor to extract the call graph? Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have read the guidance at [language-server-extension-guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide#additional-language-server-features) and the [VS-Code java extension wiki](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki). But I still could not find the way to start and interact with the language server. Could anyone provide me with an example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.